# How to solve Jest + React Native error ReferenceError?

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I have been trying to run `yarn test` in React Native project

Here is my `jest` in `package.json`

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
```

Here is my `.babelrc`

```
{  
  "presets": [    
    "es2015",
    "stage-0",
    "react-native"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs","transform-class-properties"]
    }
  }
}
```

The error is

```
ReferenceError: styleObject is not defined

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-camera-kit/src/CameraScreen/CameraKitCameraScreenStyleObject.ios.js:1:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-camera-kit/src/CameraScreen/CameraKitCameraScreenBase.js:317:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-camera-kit/src/CameraScreen/CameraKitCameraScreen.ios.js:3:1)
```

Any idea how to solve this? I have been searching everywhere still not found a correct solution.

Comment: You ever get this figured out?